# My timer doesn't work

Tags: android, image, timer, timertask

I activate a timer with 2 tasks.

1. Download 1 image/second and display this for each images
   on the sd card.
2. Display that in reading the images on the sd card for not depend of
   the Internet connection and to have a fast scroll of my 96 images to
   get a small video.

The problem is when I activate my second task with a timer of 0.4 second delay the application skip 1 or 2 images. Indeed only about 45 images displaying.

```
        MyTimerTask2 myTask = new MyTimerTask2();
        myTimer = new Timer();

        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 0 , 400);
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Please post your complete code here...

Comment: There is no way we can help with the amount of code we've been given. Also it seems like you are trying to record images and them flip thru them fast to make it seem like a video. Is there a reason why you aren't just recording a video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Handler**

```
Runnable  runnableforadd ;
                    Handler handlerforadd ;
                    handlerforadd = new Handler();
                    runnableforadd  = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          //Your Code Here
                            handlerforadd.postDelayed(runnableforadd, 400);                         } 
                    };
                    handlerforadd.postDelayed(runnableforadd, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timer doesn't work because you haven't defined your `TimerTask`. Timer needs to be created as subclass, which needs to be defined, like so:

```
   private long splashDelay = 5000;
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        //Your code here

        }

    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);

}
```

This is a `Timer` for a splash screen, but I'm sure that you can use it for whatever you need.

Here are a couple links that might help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

If you look at the first link you will see that `TimerTask` has an abstract method called `run`. Abstract methods MUST be overridden. You didn't override the run method, so your app doesn't work as expected.

Hope this helps. Best of luck!

Comment: Actually, he has defined his TimeTask class and it is TimeTask2

Comment: Not in the code listed. He instantiated the class, creating a timer object, but he didn't define the task, overriding the run method. Basically, he didn't tell the app what to do with the timer. Here is a link that should help: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

Comment: How can one instantiate an object with a class not defined. This makes no sense. It does make sense to assume that he defined a class named TimeTask2 ... why would he use one? His program can't even compile ... sry but you are wrong all about.